# Underline text using imagettftext

Tags: php, freetype, imagettftext

**My question is, how do I underline all the text in the image?

Code:**

```
function createImage($text)
{
    $text .= "\n";
    $text = wordwrap($text, 40, "\n");
    $newlines = substr_count($text, "\n");
    if($newlines == 0)
    {
        $height = 30;
    }
    else
    {
        $height = 30*$newlines-$newlines*7;
    }
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(315, $height);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $purple = imagecolorallocate($im, 97, 26, 139);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, $height, $white);
    $font = 'arialbd.ttf';

    imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 10, 20, $purple, $font, $text);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}

createImage("Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow Stackoverflow ");
```

**RESULT**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdrx9.png
I want all the text to be underlined, I've found some solutions but they're only from left to right, not depending on words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Unicode underline combining character U+0332.

You will need a loop to or clever array merge to modify the text,

```
$e = explode(' ', $text);

for($i=0;$i<count($e);$i++) {
  $e[$i] = implode('&#x0332;', str_split($e[$i]));
}

$text = implode(' ', $e);
```

Comment: createImage("Stackoverflow"); outputs S#x0332;t#0332;... with your loop, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: **&**#x0332;  the & was missing :)

Comment: Ah yeah nice one!  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by finding out dimensions of the text in pixels using [`imagettfbbox()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php), then use it as reference to draw lines beneath the text. I've played around with it and here's my try:

```
function createImage($text){

  putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

  $text = wordwrap($text, 40, "\n");  
  $padding = 10;                         // padding around text
  $uOffs = 2;                            // distance between the line and the text above it
  $uHeight = 1;                          // height of the under-line
  $lines = explode("\n", $text);         // split text in lines
  $lineLengths = array();                // will store length of each line
  $textSize = 11;
  $font = 'arialbd.ttf';

  // bounding box of all text
  $textBoundingBox = array_map('abs', imagettfbbox($textSize, 0, $font, $text));

  list($blx, $bly, $brx, $bry, $trx, $try, $tlx, $tly) = $textBoundingBox;

  // calculate image dimensions based on the bounding box data
  $x = max($brx, $trx) + ($padding * 4);
  $y = max($blx, $bly) + ($padding * 4);

  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

  // determine length of each line of text
  foreach($lines as $i => $line){
    $box = imagettfbbox($textSize, 0, $font, $line);
    $lineLengths[$i] = max($box[2], $box[4]);
  }

  $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
  $grey = imagecolorallocate($img, 128, 128, 128);
  $black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
  $purple = imagecolorallocate($img, 97, 26, 139);
  imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $x - 1, $y - 1, $white);  

  imagettftext($img, $textSize, 0, $padding + min($tlx, $blx), $padding + min($tly, $bly), $purple, $font, $text);

  // starting Y position of the under-line
  $uY = $padding +  min($tly, $bly);

  // underline text...
  foreach($lineLengths as $length){
    imagefilledrectangle($img, $padding + min($tlx, $blx), $uY + $uOffs, $padding + $length, $uY + $uOffs + $uHeight, $purple);
    $uY += 19;
  }  

  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  imagepng($img);
  imagedestroy($img);
}
```

Result:

[image]

This is a little more flexible that using Unicode chars because you have control over the line height, and position relative to the text above it.